# Why does the ArrayList remain empty yet adding objects in another class to the list works?

Tags: java, arraylist, indexoutofboundsexception

I am getting an IndexOutOfBoundsException whenever I try to use the userNames list from the MainApp class. I am, however, certain that the names are added to the list from the ServerController class, so I don't understand why the list is empty when called in another class.

I suppose this may be a problem of instantiation from checking similar problems on SO, which I have being trying to solve for quite some time but I am simply unable to do so. I would really appreciate any suggestions, TIA.

Here is my user class whose sole purpose is to store user data, i.e. names and IDs.

```
public class User {

public User() {
 }

public ArrayList<String> userNames = new ArrayList<>();

public ArrayList<String> getUserNames() {
    return this.userNames;
  }
}
```

Here is my server class: Adding the names to the userNames list is working alright.

```
public class ServerController {

  private final Server server;
  private final User user;
  private final GameConfig gameConfig;

  public ServerController(GameConfig gameConfig) {
    this.gameConfig = gameConfig;
    this.server = new Server();
    this.user = new User();
  }

  public User getUser() {
      return user;
  }
  private class ServerListener extends Listener {
   //this is where I add the names to the userNames list
    @Override
    public void received(Connection connection, Object obj) {
        server.sendToAllExceptTCP(connection.getID(), obj);
        if (obj instanceof String) {
            final String jp = (String) obj;
            user.userNames.add(jp);
        }
}
```

Here is my MainApp: I try to access the names of the users stored in userNames. The names are added to the list by the ServerController whenever a connection is received which works fine, but I get the exception in the createPlayer method.

```
public class MainApp {
 public User user = new User();

 public Game createPlayer(){

 if (("Mitspieler".equals(client1)) && ("Mitspieler".equals(client2))   && ("Mitspieler".equals(bot1))) {
        for (int i = 0; i < clients.length; i++) {
   //this is the source of the exception
            players[i + 1] = createHumanPlayer(user.getUserNames().get(i), i, restColors[i]);
        }
 }
  //....
}
```

The stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread"  
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:653)
at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:429)
at client.MainApp.createPlayer(MainApp.java:265)
```

Comment: Looks like you have 2 different `User` instances in your `ServerController` and your `MainApp` classes

Comment: Your list `userNames` must be populated with some data before you call `createPlayer`

Comment: where is `ServerController` in `MainApp` ?

Comment: @Abubakkar the list is populated in the ServerController class.

Comment: ServerController isn't called anywhere in MainApp. My idea is to add from ServerController, then use the modified list in MainApp by calling it.

Comment: `someservercontrollerobject.getUser()` should be called somewhere in your MainApp where `someservercontrollerobject` is a `new ServerController` that you get somehow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create two instances.

```
public class MainApp {
    public User user = new User(); // Instance 1
}

public class ServerController {
    private User user;

    public ServerController(GameConfig gameConfig) {
        this.user = new User(); // Instance 2
        ...
    }
}
```

Instance 1 and Instance 2 do not share any data. Instance 1 holds your added names, Instance 2 does not.

If you do not plan on having multiple instances of your controllers you could do something like

```
public class User {
    private static User USER;

    public static User getInstance() {
        if(null == USER) {
            USER = new User();
        }
        return USER;
    }
}

public class MainApp {
    public Game createPlayer() {
        User user = User.getInstance();
        List<String> userNames = user.getUserNames();
    }
}
```

`User` would then be a [Singleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern). But be aware: if you have multiple instances of `ServerController` all will use the same list of users. If that is not what you want you need to initialize `ServerController` and `MainApp` with the same instance of `User`.

Comment: How would I declare the User in MainApp?
public User user; ?
Also do you mind explaining why you moved this method to the ServerController or is it an error?

Comment: You are right, ServerController was a mistake. I also clarified how to access the singleton. Please follow the link provided to understand what a singleton does and what the limitations are. 

Why do you want to create a class `User` anyways? It is strange that it holds several user names. Are that all different names or the names of the same user? If it stores all names you could just move public `ArrayList<String> userNames = new ArrayList<>();` to `MainApp` and delete `User`.

Comment: Thanks for link! A few problems though:
1. When i try private static final User user; I get the error message that i haven't initialised it in the default constructor, how would I initialise this without creating another instance? 
2. I can't call the getInstance() method from another class- is this because of 1?

Comment: It stores names of various users, but I made a separate class as I intend to use this list in different classes, not just in MainApp, does that make sense?

Comment: Change `private` to `public` and remove `final` and you are set.

Comment: Please do some Java tutorials first and try to understand object orientation. When you want to use a singleton you need to use the `getInstance()` method in any place you want to get your `User` object. Never call `new User()` in any place (with singleton pattern).

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You create a User object in two places. In the ServerController you create and successfully add usernames to the array. Then in the MainApp you create a User object and it never has any userNames in it.